# What IP address can't be the source address in a packet?

Tags: ip, ip-address

I heard that the destination address in a packet can't be 0.0.0.0.

Is there any IP address (including special ones) which can't be the **source** address in a packet?

Thanks.

Comment: The answer to your "invalid destination address" question has the definitive answer to invalid sources as well.  https://networkengineering.stackexchange.com/a/57958

Comment: Did any answer help you? If so, you should accept the answer so that the question doesn't keep popping up forever, looking for an answer. Alternatively, you can provide and accept your own answer.

Answer (score 4):

Multicast addresses cannot be the source address of a packet.

Answer (score 0):

Only unicast ip addresses can be the source address of a packet . In IPv4 class A B C are unicast addresses . Class D addresses are multicast and cannt use as source ip address

Comment: Network classes are dead (please let them rest in peace), killed in 1993 (probably before you were born) by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (_Classless_ Inter-Domain Routing). modern networking does not use network classes.

Comment: What is the range of unicast addresses in ipv4 ??

Answer (score -1):

Multicast Ip addresses or class d ip addresses cannot be  source ip addresses.
224.0.0.0 - 239.255.255.255

Comment: Network classes are dead, killed in 1993 by RFCs 1517, 1518, and 1519, which defined CIDR (Classless Inter-Domain Routing). Modern networking does not use network classes.